# Running Django with gunicorn (on a K8s node created from a Docker Image) produces poor performance and CORS errors

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, gunicorn

I'm Deploying Django via gunicorn onto a K8s node from a Docker Image.

For a Dockerfile using `CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, i.e. standard Django dev-server, the backend services requests fine.

For a Dockerfile using `CMD gunicorn ...`, i.e. a proper staging/production server, requests are serviced SUPER-slow or not at all:

- [image: CORS Errors]
- [image: Waterfall]

Here's the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9-buster
LABEL maintainer="hq@deepspaceprogram.com"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y gcc && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y libcurl4 && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libssl-dev && \
    apt-get install -y python3-dev && \
    apt-get install -y librtmp-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libcurl4-gnutls-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql-9.3 && \
    apt-get install -y python-psycopg2
  
ENV PROJECT_ROOT /app

WORKDIR /app

# install python packages with poetry
COPY pyproject.toml .
RUN pip3 install poetry && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry install --no-dev

COPY accounts accounts
COPY analytics analytics
COPY commerce commerce
COPY documents documents
COPY leafsheets leafsheets
COPY leafsheets_django leafsheets_django
COPY marketing marketing
COPY static static

COPY manage.py .

# This should be an empty file if building for staging/production
# Else (image for local dev) it should contain the complete .env
COPY .env-for-docker-image .env

# CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

CMD gunicorn \
        --bind :8000 \
        --workers 3 \
        --worker-class gthread \
        --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm \
        --timeout 120 \
        --log-level debug \
        --log-file - \
        leafsheets_django.wsgi ;
```

Logs [here](https://gist.github.com/p-i-/5d7bbf9fee2d58a440c737d71b0891e6) show lots of "Connection Closing" messages.

In my `settings.py` I have CORS setup ok:

```
# Cors (ref: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)
if DEBUG:
    # CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # TODO: Remove after Django update
    CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
else:
    # CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ( FRONTEND_URL, )  # TODO: Remove after Django update
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ( FRONTEND_URL, )

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

What's happening? How to proceed?

Comment: For the "Connection closing" messages, that could be the issue mentioned in https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1952 with Docker's heartbeat process - is the advice in https://pythonspeed.com/articles/gunicorn-in-docker/ of any help at all for speeding things up?

Comment: For the CORS issues, https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ offers middleware that you can use to add CORS headers automatically.